# Purging unixodbc

Tags: apt, purge

As I understand, when using `apt-get purge` as opposed to *remove*, it is supposed to delete configuration files as well, not just the binaries, but when I do

```
sudo apt-get purge unixodbc
```

It's files, namely `/etc/odbcinst.ini`, `/etc/odbc.ini` and `/etc/ODBCDataSources` stay behind, why is that?

Comment: Did you tried `sudo apt remove --purge unixodbc`?

Comment: @Redbob Yes I did

Comment: These files are config files (.ini), they are not harmful. Delete them. If `/etc/ODBCDatasources`is empty, you can delete it, too.  In case you do need these config files after, do a backup before to a secure folder